# operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,3) (3,2)

Tags: python, numpy

Пытаюсь разобраться с многослойным персептроном
при обратном распространении считаю ошибки и корректирую веса.
вывожу размерность входных данных (inputs). = (150,3) и соответственно (3,150) при транспонировании

deltah также имеет размерность (150,3)

hidden1 тоже

в итоге, когда пытаюсь запустить код:

```
                deltah = hidden1*beta*(1.0-hidden1)*(np.dot(deltao,np.transpose(weights2)))     #  ошибки скрытых  нейронов
     58         print("deltah ", deltah, "\t", "shape", deltah.shape)
---> 59         updatew1 = teta*(np.dot(np.transpose(inputs),deltah)) + Alfa*updatew1    # корр. весов
     60         print("trans", np.transpose(inputs).shape)
     61         print("inputs", inputs, "updatew1", updatew1)
```

получаю ошибку`operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,3) (3,2)` на участке выше
но, когда вместо `updatew1 = teta*(np.dot(np.transpose(inputs),deltah)) + Alfa*updatew1`пишу

```
updatew1 = teta*(np.dot(np.transpose(inputs),deltah[:, :-1])) + Alfa*updatew1
```

все прекрасно, хотя по идее, `deltah[:, :-1]`- матрица, за исключением последнего столбца

shape у deltah[:, :-1] получается (150, 2)

по моей логике, (3, 150) * (150, 3) лучше, чем (3, 150) * (150, 2), но видимо нет. помогите распутаться :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас проблема не в умножении, а в сложении.

Умножение `np.dot(np.transpose(inputs),deltah)` даёт массив размером `(3,3)`, а произведение `np.dot(np.transpose(inputs),deltah[:,:-1])` дает массив  размером `(3,2)`

Соответственно, если у вас `inputw1` имеет размер `(3,2)`, то сложение c массивом размером `(3,3)` выдаёт ошибку.